# Rails generate model: Cannot find ansi-1.5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have just started up a new Rails application and I am trying to generate a model. When I run the command:

```
rails g model mod name:string
```

I get the following error message:

> Could not find ansi-1.5.0 in any of the sources
>   Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I have run `bundle install` and I get the line `Using ansi 1.5.0` so it doesn't seem to be a bundler problem. I did double check both `bundle show ansi` and `gem list --local` and both show ansi 1.5.0 is installed. Does anyone know why I may be getting this message? Let me know if there is anymore information I should provide. Thanks.

Comment: Is `bundle exec rails g model mod name:string` giving the same error message?

Comment: @katafrakt, thanks for the comment. It seems that after a bit of a break and a restart its working now. Thanks for trying to help though!